# Why is the compiler not seeing the default parameter value specified?

Tags: c++

Observe the following interface/implementation:

**properties.h**

```
class Property
{
  public:
    Property(PropertyCollection * propertyCollection, std::string key, 
      std::string value, uint32_t identifier);
```

**properties.cpp**

```
Property::Property(PropertyCollection * propertyCollection, 
  std::string key, std::string value, uint32_t identifier = 0)
  : propertyCollection(propertyCollection), key(key), value(value), 
    identifier(identifier) {}
```

As you can see, I have a default initializer for the last argument.

However, I still get this Eclipse error:

**main.cpp**

```
Properties properties (*file);
Property property (&properties, std::string("Cats"), std::string("Rule"));
```

> no matching function for call to ‘Property::Property(Properties*, std::string, std::string)’

EDIT: `Properties` inherits from `PropertyCollection`.  `PropertyCollection` is a pure virtual class.

```
 +----------------------+
 |    <<pure virtual>>  |
 | PropertyCollection   |
 +----------------------+
 |                      |
 +----------------------+
             ^
             |
             +
+-----------------------+
| Properties            |
|-----------------------|
|                       |
+-----------------------+
```

In Java I'd think of `Properties` **as a ** `PropertyCollection` and just pass the reference as-is.  However, in C++, must I cast the pointer to the base class somehow?

Edit: Guess not.  The sole problem was the location of the default initializer.

Comment: Perhaps because `PropertyCollection` != `Properties` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The why**

It seems as if you are including `properties.h` from your *main* source code and later link against what is inside `properties.cpp`, which is totally fine in trivial cases.

But when doing what you are doing there's no way for the compiler to know (at time of compiling *main*) that the constructor you are trying to invoke has a default parameter (this isn't know until you are linking against `properties.cpp`).

In *main*  the compiler only knows what you have told it, more specifically it only knows about

```
Property::Property (PropertyCollection * propertyCollection, std::string key, 
  std::string value, uint32_t identifier);
```

---

**The solution**

The simple, and recommended, solution is to move the *default-value specification* to the constructor declaration in `properties.h`, this way the compiler will have all the information required to make things work the way you intend.

---

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the default parameter in the member function *declaration*, i.e. in the header file, not in its *definition*:

```
class Property
{
  public:
    Property(PropertyCollection * propertyCollection, std::string key, 
      std::string value, uint32_t identifier = 0);
```

In the code you've shown, `main` can only see `Property::Property(PropertyCollection*, std::string, std::string, uint32_t)`.

Comment: FYI. I used your suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution has already provided in a the answer by juanchopanza. I'm going to present how the .h file and the .cpp file should look after the change.

**properties.h**

```
class Property
{
  public:
    Property(PropertyCollection * propertyCollection, std::string key, 
      std::string value, uint32_t identifier = 0);
```

**properties.cpp**

```
Property::Property(PropertyCollection * propertyCollection, 
  std::string key, std::string value, uint32_t identifier)
  : propertyCollection(propertyCollection), key(key), value(value), 
    identifier(identifier) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor:

```
Property(PropertyCollection * propertyCollection, std::string key, std::string value);
```

Your constructor:

```
Property(Property * propertyCollection, std::string key, std::string value);
```

Pass an address of an object of `PropertyCollection`, or create new constructor.

Comment: Agh... getting lost in the verbiage.  Thank you.

Comment: Your passing a pointer of `Property` when you should be passing a pointer of `PropertyCollection`

Comment: Actually I was passing a pointer of `Properties`.  I need to change some verbiage... it's far too confusing to have `Property` `Properties` and `PropertyCollection`.  Anyway, what if `Properties` inherits from `PropertyCollection`?  In Java I'd get away with this code.